# Opening a TStream on stdin/stdout in a Delphi console app

Tags: delphi, console-application, stdout, stdin, tstream

I'm trying to write a Delphi console application that creates a TStream for its standard input, and another TStream for its standard output.

(It will be launched by a host app with its input and output redirected to pipes, and will be passing binary data to/from that host app, so TStream will be much better-suited to the task than ReadLn/WriteLn.)

How do I go about opening a TStream on standard input or standard output?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
  InputStream := THandleStream.Create(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
  OutputStream := THandleStream.Create(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));
```

Give that a go..

Comment: Indeed it does, very nicely. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you'll need the Windows unit in your uses clause for the GetStdHandle function.

Comment: Is there a cross-platform way to do the same?